# API Gateway Error : Site can't be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I followed the process from this video : [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxpM_JN28GE)

I created the Lambda function, and the API, and when I am testing in the API Gateway editor, it is working properly. Giving status 200 and correct output.

[image]

Here when I deployed I gave the `url + /opencv` as said in the video, but the browser doesn't give any output and gave the result `site not reachable`.

[image]

I also tried without the resource `/opencv` and when I run the url which I get after deployment I get `{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}` error.

So, how am I able to get the output while testing in the AWS tool as shown in the picture above but after deployment I am not able to get. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Stages under Resources and verify the URL and try to create a new stage. i just followed the same steps and i can see it is working fine. In order to reproduce, i deleted the Stage and verified it gives me the error which you have mentioned. So try to reproduce the steps again by creating a new stage under resources as it will enable you to have auto new URL and then verify. Incase if it does not work, do share your stage Screenshot next time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I deleted the stage and tried again with `url + /opencv` and it gave a new error : `{"message":"Forbidden"}` And again when I check then it gave the previous error only.

Comment: I created a new api and now its working.
And I am sure I didn't miss any step earlier.

Answer (score 0):

For others that get the same issue. One solution is to wait a bit:
I also had this error when first time deploying the API GW. It then started working fine ~5-10min later.